# Certificate Error while Deploying python code in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I tried deploying python code using google app engine.
But I got Error Below:

> certificate verify failed

I had included proxy certificate in `urlfetch_cacerts.py` and enabled '`validate_certificate`' in `urlfetch_stub.py` by _`API_CALL_VALIDATE_CERTIFICATE_DEFAULT = True`.But I still get the error..
Can you suggest any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading Python to 2.7.8 or later versions fixed the issue.

EDIT: 
Also check if you are using **google app engine SDK 1.8.1** or later version. As of version SDK 1.8.1 the `cacerts.txt` has been renamed to `urlfetch_cacerts.txt`. You can try removing cacerts.txt file to fix the problem.

Comment: Upgrading Python works fine. 
Renaming of cacerts.txt works, but only temporary, it has to be done for every update of the SDK.